# Can value of predicted probability from logistic model be greater than one?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, prediction

I derived a multivariate logistic model from my data containing a single binary response and five predictors.

I tried to calculate the predicted probabilities of one of the binary predictor (smoking) keeping the other, continuous, variables at their mean values. I get values greater than one.

Is it possible to get predicted probability value greater than one? Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this can never happen (if the model is correct).

Comment: Can you show *exactly* what you did to get a value greater than one? With more details we can probably identify the error.

Comment: It is not possible using a logistic regression with the logit function as the link function, as the the inverse of logit has (0,1) as its range. It is however possible if you use a linear normal model for this kind of data (this can clearly give results that are difficult to interpret).

Comment: @swmo Actually i did the model using glm function in R. After reading your comment I looked in to the model and found that i used the default gaussian distribution rather than a binomial with logit link. Will that can be a cause for this? In mean time i will try to derive the predicted probabilties again and see the values i get.

Comment: @d0ct0r, yes, using the gaussian option in the glm function in R could definitely do this, as this would amount to using the linear normal model (or whatever you want to call it). This can easily give predictions outside of the (0,1) range. This will not happen if you use logistic regression in glm (the binomial family).

Comment: Now I didn't get values greater than one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The OP has explained in comments that they by error used the R `glm` function, but forgot to specify the argument `family=binomial`, that is, used the default gaussian family (with identity link.) But that is the usual (least squares) linear regression, not logistic regression, and clearly can give predictions outside the interval $(0,1)$.